# Installing a package in Texmaker

Tags: packages, installing

I want to install `pgfornament` package. I have TeX Live 2013 installed on my Windows 8.1 system. Now, I downloaded the `pgfornament` package and copied the `.sty` file to the path

```
C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\tex\latex\pgfornament
```

but yet I get the error in Texmaker that the `pgfornament.sty` file is not found. What should I do?